# HttpClient PostAsync Parameter Incorrect

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I just deployed Windows 10 64-bit Education on my Macbook Air, a slightly updated installer from my main development PC which also runs Windows 10 64-bit Education.

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and downloaded all of the nugget packaged for my project solution, exactly how I've done it on my development PC.

My problem is when I run production code that we use all the time inhouse and have received no complaints from our clients, it doesn't work on my new setup / installation.

We have a method to login users with a simple username and password field. When we call a PostAsync method it sends up the form data to our servers. I've used Postman and have received a correct response. The code hasn't been modified or changed at all and is known working code. I'm also working off coffee shop and home wife, which is the only difference. I haven't tried getting this to work in the office yet. Out clients go to coffee shops and use home wifi all the time..

Any thoughts and suggestions would be greatly appreciated

**Vague Exception - but my code hasn't changed at all?**

```
{System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.
The parameter is incorrect.
at Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync(Uri uri, IHttpContent content)
at CoreProject.Helpers.LogginHelper.<UserLogin>d__1.MoveNext()}
```

EDIT:

URI setup code

```
Uri uri = new URI("https://oururi.com/login");
```

HttpClient setup code

```
// disable caching
// https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79e98534-5d8e-4879-acbe-7a457ee2a7ad/windowswebhttphttpclient-turn-off-caching?forum=winappswithcsharp
var RootFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
RootFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache;
RootFilter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(RootFilter);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("email", email);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("pw", password);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apiVersion", "2.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("version", CacheHelper.getVersionString());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("appID", CacheHelper.Config.AppId());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("platform", "windows");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("updated", LocalSettingsHelper.GetContentLastUpdatedTimestamp());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("bundleID", CacheHelper.Config.BundleId());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("vendorID", Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager.AdvertisingId);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("deviceType", UtilityHelper.DeviceType());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("osVersion", AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamilyVersion);

String termsValue = didAcceptTerms ? "1" : "0";
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("terms", termsValue);
return httpClient;
```

Method call that throws the exception

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, null);
```

Comment: Can you show us the ocde that throws the exception?

Comment: I updated my question with some code

Comment: Hum.. You code is correct. Uri is correct. Passing null parameter is correct.Check if passing `new StringContent()` instead of `null` works.

Comment: I'm using `Windows.Web.Http` so `StringContent()` is incompatible for me. The `PostAsync` method takes an `IHttpContent` parameter and a clear implementation is not obvious to me.

Comment: But also I'm not sure i have to pass anything to that since it's not needed. So you are right it's an empty content, but PostAsync should handle that